# Docker Aspnet core Setting physical directory path

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I am trying to run the aspnet core application In docker container. I am having issues with physical file provider.

In my application startup.cs I am using following code to for a physical file provider and map with alias

```
  app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("G:\\Work\\LMS\\lms-data"),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/lms-data"),
            EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false
        });
```

Now My docker file is

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5001

COPY ["SharedKernal/SharedKernal.csproj", "SharedKernal/"]
COPY ["LMS.Entities/LMS.Entities.csproj", "LMS.Entities/"]
COPY ["LMS.Core/LMS.Core.csproj", "LMS.Core/"]
COPY ["LMS.Infrastructure/LMS.Infrastructure.csproj", "LMS.Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["LMS.Web/LMS.Web.csproj", "LMS.Web/"]

RUN dotnet restore "LMS.Web/LMS.Web.csproj"
RUN mkdir /lms-data

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/app/LMS.Web"

CMD [ "/bin/bash","-c","dotnet restore && dotnet watch run" ]
```

**My docker compose file is:**

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  lmsapp:
    image: lmsapp
    container_name: lmsappv1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: "/app/LMS.Web"
    volumes: 
      - ".:/app"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "5001:5001"
    networks: 
      - mongo_network

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo_db
    networks: 
      - mongo_network
    ports: 
      - "27017:27017"

networks: 
  mongo_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Now when ever i run the the command docker-compose up after running docker-compose build

I receive following error

```
System.ArgumentException: The path must be absolute. (Parameter 'root')
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root)
   at LMS.Web.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in /app/LMS.Web/Startup.cs:line 130
```

> **How to solve this error?**

**The other issue I am facing when ever I run the docker-compose up it always restore packages. How to avoid that?**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("G:\\Work\\LMS\\lms-data"),
```

Try this:

```
FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"lms-data"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).